# Are the advent facility locations randomized or difficulty based?

Tags: xcom-2

I'm playing on the second hardest difficulty. I'm doing okay in actual missions, but I'm severely struggling with the Avatar project, which is really close to finishing.

The reason for this is that I started in west asia, but after the tutorial blacklist site, both other sites spawned all the way over in America, where I can't reach them until I first make contact.

However, to make contact with those, I first have to fill an entire chain of contacts over there, struggling with the contact limit and the amount of intel it costs to spread out over such a large area.

Did I just get extremely unlucky that both of the facilities spawned as far away as possible? Or is this difficulty based, meaning that on higher difficulties, your facilities spawn as far away as possible?

Comment: And the third facility also spawned in America, triggering 10 days for me to get there using 3 contact slots. GG game, gg... o_O;

Comment: Don't forget, there are other ways to counter Avatar progress, like completing the Skulljack encounters. The first Skulljack also leads to another story mission you can do, which may have a more convenient location.

Comment: Already did all the story missions I was able to do at that point, it was literally just those advent facilities I was after.

Comment: Not sure if you're aware, but when the Avatar project fills, you're given a period of time (I think it's 14 days on Commander) to reduce the Avatar progress before you lose the game. Taking advantage of this extra time can be crucial early on for managing Avatar progress on higher difficulties.

Comment: Well aware of that, Chris. Problem is, those 14 extra days were nowhere near enough to reach those facilities in America.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, I started the game 4 times until now and every time it was **completely random**...

My current game is on Legend and my HQ is in East Asia. I have 2 Avatar facilities, one in West Asia, one in Australia.

Also keep in mind that various missions or hacking towers can lead to discovering more facilities.

**I understand your frustrations but try not to worry too much about the avatar project completion. Instead, always try to ride the clock.**

What I usually do, I wait until the avatar project is almost done, this including the final countdown. In the mean time I try to be as prepared as possible and enable 1 or 2 facility missions. After the countdown is close to an end I do a facility mission, making the avatar project to reset the clock and go down 2 squares. Then I wait again for countdown, do another mission and so on. That boost in the beginning is very important. Without it, playing on Legend is almost impossible... so take your time!

Comment: Going to accept this question, as I believe it is the right one. Restarted the game on the same difficulty and this time around, I had far more manageable locations, not to mention more useful pickup bonuses to get there like power and + resistance contacts. Guess I just got super unlucky the first time around.